# выводит неправильный результат разницы

Tags: php

Возникила такая проблема, нужно вывести разницу двух переменных
$balance и $total_limit
Но местами выводится значение в периоде.
к примеру, когда

```
$balance = 1739.59 
$total_limit = 1730
```

то результат выполнения кода таков:

```
<?php
$diff = ($balance - $total_limit);
echo $diff;
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите пожалуйста как исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так:

```
$balance = 1739.59;
$total_limit = 1730;

$diff = ($balance - $total_limit);
echo round($diff, 2);
```

или

```
$balance = 1739.59;
$total_limit = 1730;

$diff = ($balance - $total_limit);
echo number_format($diff, 2);
```

Comment: Сделал с round но думал есть вариант поправильнее.

Comment: @FALKOR, ну как минимум я вам два различных варианта написал

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работать с числами которым нужна точность в любом языке програмирования - переводите их до целых потом обратно. Если интерестно почему так почитайте про потерю точности на дробных значениях.

```
<?php
$balance = 1739.59;
$total_limit = 1730;

$diff = ($balance * 100 - $total_limit * 100) / 100;
echo $diff;
```